# Juniper: How to see OSPF routes that didn't make the routing table

Tags: path, metrics, juniper, ospf

I have a specific scenario:

There are 2 paths leading to a given OSPF prefix:
-Both of the paths are learnt via OSPF
-Prefix CIDRs are the same size
-Both OSPF "preference" value is unchanged (so is the default: 10)

My problem is that only a single Path is put inside my routing-table
( I would assume it is because one of the OSPF path's cost was lower than the other's).

I got 2 questions:
-What command do I need to put into Juniper CLI in order to see the "not-so-best" OSPF paths (that actually didnt make it into the routing table)
-How do I see the metric of each individual path toward a given prefix.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

OSPF does not advertise routes, it advertises LSAs.  You need look at the OSPF "database" to see the different LSAs, and you need to understand the LSA types and the Djikstra algorithm.